# Styling a Div Class within Div ID

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has the following div element:

```
<div id="name" class="class_name">
```

Which of the following should I use to style the class?

```
#name .class_name
name .class_name
#name class_name
```

Answer (score 4):

Just `#name` would be enough to apply the style only to that specific element:

```
#name {
   // your styles here
}
```

If you want to apply the style to all the elements using the `class_name` class, then you can use:

```
.class_name {
   // your styles here
}
```

Comment: @chris: Then the `divs` all lived happily ever after :)

Answer (score 1):

#name .class_name will apply to the children elements of your div with the .class_name class.

There must not be any spaces between.

You should use: `#name.class_name` because it is the correct syntax.

But, when working with identifiers, it should be enough to use it alone.

```
#name {
  // some properties
}
```

But let's say you have a unique block, which inherits some generic styles, then you could use #idenifier.class to mix styles.

```
#comments {
    width: 453px;
}

#comments.links
{
   border: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right you use

```
#name .class_name
```

as in

```
#name .class_name {
    color:#000;
}
```

But actually you don't need to do that.
If `#name` and `.class_name` are oly used in that div you can just drop the `.class_name`. Otherwise, if you use multiple stuff with `.class_name` that don't share the same properties as div `#name`, you should separate them.

```
.class_name {
    color:#000;
}
#name {
    width:600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's should be unique, so there isn't much point in styling both the id of the div and the class_name.

Just using the ID of the div is fine if that's your goal.

```
#name
{
   //styles
}
```

If you want to style every div that has that class name, then just use

```
.class_name
{
   //styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about CSS selectors here:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref

In the CSS you can reference it by class:

```
.class_name { color: green; }
```

or by id using #id

```
#name { color: green; }
```

or by element type

```
div { color: green; }
```

//or by combinations of the above

```
div.class_name { color: green; }
div#name { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have #name and .class_name styled, but for some reason you want to style

```
<div id="name" class="class_name"></div>
```

(that is, a specific style to the element with an id of "name" AND a class of "class_name"), you can use

```
#name.class_name {
/* note the absence of space between the id and class selector */
    ...
}
```

Bear in mind that this selector is not supported by Internet Explorer 6.